# Криво отображется меню в IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Сделал плиточное меню для сайта. У некоторых пользователей в IE (даже в 9-м) плитка отображается криво (в других браузера проблема не возникает). Помогите исправить, пожалуйста.

[image: -]

```
#lnkm {
  display: block;
  height: 100px !important;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0px 15px 0px;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  background: #ffffff;
}

#lnkm:hover {
  display: block;
  height: 100px !important;
  width: 100%;
  background: #dddddd !important;
  background-color: #dddddd !important;
}


.lnkm_l {
  display: block;
  border: 0px;
  font-family: tahoma;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #000000 !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.lnkm_i {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: 000000;
  border: 0px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.lnkm_t {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 25px;
}

.lnkm_ok {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #BDBDBD;
}

.lnkm_ok:before {
  content: "";
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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);
  background-size:cover;
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  display:inline-block;
 }


 .lnkm_not {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  }

.lnkm_not:before {
  content: "";
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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);
  background-size:cover;
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  display:inline-block;
 }
 .lnkm_not:after {
  content: "Материал может содержать неактуальную информацию (планируется обновление)";
  }
```

[код](https://jsfiddle.net/ujukxLs9/1/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ujukxLs9/1/ - этот код в IE9 корректно отображает

Comment: У кого-то да, у кого-то - нет. Хотелось бы узнать, как сделать, чтобы корректно отображалось в более ранних версиях IE.

Comment: подключается через условные комментарии - <!--[if lte IE 8]><link href="css/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><![endif]--> и прописываете отдельно стили

Comment: @soledar10, спасибо. а что в этом стиле прописать, чтобы меню не разъехалось?

Answer (score 1):

Ещё, если в head'e документа, у Вас нет такого, то добавьте:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```